# WDS Bridge estabilish connection between Router and AP

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

I want to estabilish connection between my router Asus DSL-N55U-B Dual-Band and AP D-Link DAP-2230, but I am not sure if I understand how to do it. AP should act like wireless only receiver with LAN output.

I can get to setup page on both (on the D-link via assigning static IP).

I do not know how to pair these two devices. On the access point I have settings like Site Survey which I think has no effect on pairing. On the root router Asus I have WDS settings with this text:

> Wireless - Bridge
>   Bridge (or named WDS - Wireless Distribution System) function allows your DSL-N55U-B to connect to an access point wirelessly. WDS may also be considered a repeater mode. But with this method, the devices connected to the access point will only be able to use half of the access point's original wireless speed.
>   Note:The function only support [Open System/NONE, Open System/WEP] security authentication method.
>   To enable WDS to extend the wireless signal, please follow these steps :
>   Select [WDS Only] or [Hybrid] mode and add MAC address of APs in Remote AP List.
>   Ensure that this wireless router and the AP you want to connect to use the same channel.
>   Key in the remote AP mac in the remote AP list and open the remote AP's WDS management interface, key in the this router's MAC address.
>   To get the best performance, please go to Advanced Settings > Wireless > General and assign the same channel bandwidth, control channel, and extension channel to every router in the network.
>   You are currently using the Auto channel bandwidth. Click Here to modify.
>   You are currently using the Auto channel. Click Here to modify.

And selection of modes: Hybrid, AP only, WDS only; and AP list enable. Which one to choose?

Is this device capable of bridge without dd-wrt? I have done some testing but cannot see any results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just for clarification you are going to use the D-Link DAP-2230 to connect to wireless (SSID) of main Asus router & provide the internet via the cord to wired device? Basically acting like a wireless adapter? If so you do not need WDS & the DAP-2230 supports this in 'wireless client' mode so it doesn't need DD-WRT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding the concept of Wireless Client. It seemed like the WPA credentials were supposed to be set for the AP itself and not for the Root Router.

Very poor manual and misleading labels. Nowadays tech is targeted for an experienced.

Comment: Also in order to prevent most AP's from providing their own LAN (DHCP) disable the DHCP server or activate "Bridging" mode on the router. There are different modes, choose the one recommended by your manufacturer or  most appropriate for your situation.